# 'dict' object has no attribute 'widgetName' error tkinter python3

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, tkinter

First the code:

**main.py**

```
import string
from app import App
group1=[ "spc", "bspc",",","."]#letters, space, backspace(spans mult layers)
# add in letters one at a time
for s in string.ascii_lowercase:
    group1.append(s)
group2=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, "tab ","ent","lAR" ,"rAR" , "uAR", "dAR"]
group3= []
for s in string.punctuation:
    group3.append(s)#punc(spans mult layers)
group4=["copy","cut","paste","save","print","cmdW","quit","alf","sWDW"] #kb shortcut
masterGroup=[group1,group2,group3,group4]
myApp =App({"testFKey":[3,2,2,None})
```

**app.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import static_keys
import dynamic_keys
import key_labels
class App(tk.Frame):

def __init__(inputDict,self, master=None):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
    self.createWidgets(self, inputDict)
def createWidgets(self,inDict):
    top=self.winfo_toplevel()
    top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    tempDict = {}
    for k,v in inDict.items():
            if 1<=v[0]<=3:
                tempDict[k] = static_keys(k,*v[1:])
            elif v[0] ==4:
                tempDict[k] = dynamic_keys(k,*v[1:])
            elif  v[0]==5:
                tempDict[k] = key_labels(k,*v[1:])
    for o in tempDict:
        tempDict[o].grid()
    return tempDict
```

**static_keys.py**

```
import tkinter
class StaticKeys(tkinter.Label):
    """class for all keys that just are initiated then do nothing
    there are 3 options
    1= modifier (shift etc)
    2 = layer
    3 = fkey, eject/esc"""
    def __init__(t,selector,r,c, parent,self):
        if selector == 1:
            tkinter.Label.__init__(master=parent, row=r, column=c, text= t, bg ='#676731')
        if selector == 2:
            tkinter.Label.__init__(master=parent, row=r, column=c, text= t, bg ='#1A6837')
        if selector == 3:
            tkinter.Label.__init__(master=parent, row=r, column=c, text= t, bg ='#6B6966')
```

When I run main.py I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/kblMaker/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    myApp =App({"testFKey":[3,2,2]})
  File "/Users/fozbstudios/Desktop/kblMaker/app.py", line 8, in __init__
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2574, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2067, in __init__
    self.widgetName = widgetName
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'widgetName'
```

Why is this? I have a hunch that I need to possibly do more attribute = self.attribute stuff in the inits, but I don't know. That construct confuses me. Also, is the style good? It doesn't seem like i seem many people tasking all their gui construction into one function. If it is poor, please suggest alternatives. Thanks so much for your help!

**update1**
 I followed the advice of @zhangyangyu by changing the order of arguments and got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/kblMaker/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    myApp =App(d)
  File "/Users/fozbstudios/Desktop/kblMaker/app.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.createWidgets(self, inputDict)
TypeError: createWidgets() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

**update2**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/kblMaker/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    myApp =App(d)
  File "/Users/fozbstudios/Desktop/kblMaker/app.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.createWidgets(inputDict)
  File "/Users/fozbstudios/Desktop/kblMaker/app.py", line 20, in createWidgets
    tempDict[k] = StaticKeys(k,*v[1:])
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'parent' and 'self'
```

**update3**
now got it down to missing only one arg by adding a parent string in d, changed main.py to reflect. Seems like its wanting me too pass a self, even hough I know i shouldn't

Answer (score 2):

```
def __init__(inputDict,self, master=None):
```

This part of your code is wrong. In your code, `self` is the argument you pass in and `inputDict` will be the instance of the class. You'd better use:

```
def __init__(self, inputDict, master=None):
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/kblMaker/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    myApp =App(d)
  File "/Users/fozbstudios/Desktop/kblMaker/app.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.createWidgets(self, inputDict)
TypeError: createWidgets() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: `self.createWidgets(self, inputDict)` should be `self.createWidgets(inputDict)`. `self` is passed implicitly and you do not pass it. I suggest a review for Python class.

Comment: **Fixed that. Now getting** Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/kblMaker/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    myApp =App(d)
  File "/Users/fozbstudios/Desktop/kblMaker/app.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.createWidgets(inputDict)
  File "/Users/fozbstudios/Desktop/kblMaker/app.py", line 20, in createWidgets
    tempDict[k] = StaticKeys(k,*v[1:])
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'parent' and 'self'